# Good examples on custom Rest using Django Restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying for last two days to write a custom rest interface - Get and Post using djangorestframework. Get works without any issues.

However POST does not work.

The following is what I did :
Wrote a forms.py file with the following

```
import logging
from django import forms
class AddUserLocationAndDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    """A simple form with some of the most important pygments settings.
    The code to be highlighted can be specified either in a text field, or by URL.
    We do some additional form validation to ensure clients see helpful error responses."""

    user = forms.CharField(
                           label='User',
                           max_length=200)
    fbemail = forms.CharField(
                           label='Facebook Email',
                           max_length=200)
```

Wrote corresponding view.py file like this:

```
import logging
from djangorestframework.views import View
from djangorestframework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from djangorestframework.response import Response
from djangorestframework import status

from forms import AddUserLocationAndDetailsForm

class AddUserLocationAndDetailsView(View):
    """
    This view adds details of a user. 
    This view also performs functionalities to update location of a user if the user already exists.
    """
    form = AddUserLocationAndDetailsForm

    def get(self, request):
       return "you have reached get"

    def post(self, request):
        return Response(status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

After doing this when I run the server I get web page for entering two fields. But whenever I submit POST I get the error "This field is required.". I have no clue what is happening. No idea how to debug this as well since it never hits "post" function in class AddUserLocationAndDetailsView. 
I ve followed how they have done here in example: http://django-rest-framework.org/examples/views.html

But it simply does not work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the import:

```
from <yourapp>.forms import AddUserLocationAndDetailsForm
```

in stead of:

```
from forms import AddUserLocationAndDetailsForm
```

not sure if that helps.... because this would give an error on runserver or hitting the page
Do you have debug mode on in your settings file?

and can you give your urls file also?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a model like "Request" or "Task" and manage objects of this model with CRUD requests, including additional work in the processing.
This way you benefit also from permission / authentication provided by REST framework, Historical data